# Storing characters obtained from fgetc

Tags: c, assembly

I am doing a piece of homework that requires me to remove white spaces from a piece of assembly language as well as the comments after a semi colon. For example `mov  %a,0x01        ; blah blah blah`. I want to be able to store all the characters in an array before the semi colon and print them. Any ideas how to do it since im a C noob.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char ch;
    int i;
    //char line[] = "mov %a,0x01     ; system call number (sys_exit)\n";
    char label[100];
    char *infilename = argv[1];
    int length = strlen(line);

    FILE *infile = fopen(infilename, "rb");

    printf("         ");
    while (1) { 
        ch = fgetc(infile);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;

        if (isspace(ch) == 0) {
            printf("%c", ch);               
        }
    }
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is really no need to store the characters, you can decide whether it needs to be printed or not right away.

Comment: @Jester you're probably right but in matters of one's homework there's often a disparity between what's necessary and what the requirements are.

Comment: You'll want to remove the whitespace between `%a,0x01` and `;` too. But limit the whitespace between `mov` and `%a,0x01` to a single space.

Comment: Many ways. But for starters why not just stop the loop when a `;` character is encountered?

Comment: I suggest using `fgets` and `strtok`. Note that `fgets` stores the characters in an array.

Comment: Have doubts that the input file is a binary file.  Recommend `fopen(infilename, "r");`

Comment: "to store all the characters in an array " code needs to 1) set a maximum limit of array size, 2) use increasing  dynamic memory allocation or 3) [Avoid the array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35708810/2410359) needs all together as suggest by [@jester](http://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester)

Comment: ok thanks for the help everyone! will try this all out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple state machine: Is incoming text part of a comment?

No need to save the line, just print as it arrives.

```
bool IsComment = false;
int ch;  // Insure to use type `int` for proper `EOF` compare and `isspace()` usage.
while ((ch = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
  if (IsComment) {
    if (ch == '\n') {
      IsComment = false;
      fputc(ch, stdout); // end comment
    }
  } else if (isspace(ch) && ch != '\n') {
    ; // do not print space
  } else if (ch == ';') {
    IsComment = true;  // start comment
  } else {
    fputc(ch, stdout);
  }
}
```

Comment: `ch` must be `int` for the `EOF` test to work reliably

Comment: @chqrlie Agree `ch` needs to be `int`, as in this answer not only for the correct test of `EOF`, but also for portable usage of `isspace()`.

Comment: indeed `isspace()` should not be called with a `char` argument.

Comment: hi thanks for the responce, can you quickly explain if (iscomment) line?

Comment: A `';'` begins a comment like `"; blah blah blah"` and should not be printed. `IsComment` is flag denoting if code is reading comment text or regular text.

Comment: Thanks for your help! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`ch` should be defined as `int` so the value `EOF` can be stored and distinguished from all `unsigned char` values returned before the end of file.

Furthermore, the line `int length = strlen(line);` refers to an undefined variable `line`.

Here is a more complete version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ch, filter = 0, prefix = 1;
    char *infilename = argv[1];
    FILE *infile = fopen(infilename, "r");

    if (infile != NULL) {
        while ((ch = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) {
            if (prefix) {
                prefix = 0;
                printf("         "); // print the line prefix
            }
            if (ch == ';') { 
                filter = 1;   // filter characters until \n
            } else
            if (ch == '\n') {
                filter = 0;   // end of line: reset filter
                prefix = 1;   // and will print the prefix on next line
                putchar(ch);
            } else 
            if (!filter && !isspace(ch)) {
                putchar(ch);  // output character unless filtered          
            }
        }
        fclose(infile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- `filter` is a boolean variable that determines whether characters should be output or not.  By default, `filter=0`, so characters are output unless they ar white space.  If the character read is a `;`, filter is set to `1` so the `;` and the following characters are filtered out until the end of line, which is not filtered out. This schemes implements comment removal.
- `prefix` is a boolean variable set at the beginning of the file and after each linefeed to tell the loop to output a `"    "` at the beginning of the next line, before outputting any characters.  I inferred you wanted this behavior from the `printf("     ");` before the loop in your code, but it might be there for a different purpose.
- This simple filter may be incorrect as it removes all space characters, including those in character string literals.  It also assumes a `;` always introduces a comment, but `;` in a string literal does not...  You might need to understand more of the assembly syntax to implement this filter properly.

Comment: Maybe you mean `ch` instead of `c`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: of course... I would have picked `c` over `ch`, and so did my fingers.

Comment: hi thanks for your thorough response but can you explain the use of filter and prefix?

Comment: @Jim: can you please click on the grey check mark below the answer score to mark it as accepted?